# One company - two countries US and Australia. Same content

Tags: seo, domains

My friend owns a website in the US selling his product (a jewelery brand) and I'm about to run the same business here in Australia.
He owns `.com` and I obviously have `.com.au`.

What am I about to face in terms of search? What specific settings will I need to set?

I'm trying to produce my content a bit differently (product descriptions mostly) but I've also decided that I'll run a blog on it too (he doesn't).

Comment: I recommend the seo tag, since it seems that you are mostly asking about search engine results. Is that your biggest concern here or are there other concerns?

Comment: THanks for answering Stephen. My Concern is mostly for SEO in general: I'm afraid to "confuse" google, hence affect our ranking and so on!

Answer (score 1):

So is this the exact same brand as you said it's the same website?

You will need to set up search console for Google and bing webmaster tools to target countries per domain.

Because you are using ccTLD's Google will be pretty good at working out its the same brand for different countries.

If it's the same content you do run the risk hindering ranks if you don't use hreflang tags. Hreflang is for language targeting not country targeting though. However, you mentioned you are going to change the content which is best. Ensure it is unique enough.

There shouldn't be competition between the two but ensure your back links are location relevant to further enforce the countries you are targeting.

Comment: Hi there and thank you for taking the time for asking. Brand name is exactly the same, but main domain will be also the same - only difference is : rowingjewelry (USA) vs rowingjewellery (AU) and ccTLD's.

Comment: And yes I'm trying to write different product description and add a blog on the website, which I think it will make a huge difference. We are also thinking of linking ourselves in our website. ( saying to customer that if they are located in Australia or Asia then they should come to me- cheaper and faster shipping) And I will do the same on my  website.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you will both be competing against each other. Linking to each other is a good idea, you could add a drop down in the header and footer for visitors to choose their country. This will make it easier if you branch out into other countries.